# How can I duplicate this cut that I modeled?

Tags: modeling

I want to duplicate that cut according to the line I have drawn. Can I somehow duplicate the cut that I modeled?

Screenshot -
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't think so, you should have done them at the same time, now you can delete some parts, duplicate this part, then bridge the duplications...

Comment: You can create several loopcuts, select them and bevel. Or you can select a loopcut and run Offset Edges Slide to create loopcuts around the selection. Copying selection won't work without deleting some geometry and reconnecting since the original geometry to copy is already connected to the rest of the mesh